# Periodic solutions of $y'''+ay'+byy'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find all possible periodic solutions for the equation $$
y'''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)y'(x)=0,
$$
where $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. I believe that this equation shouldn't have periodic solution for all possible values of $b$ and $c$, in the same way $y''+by=0$ has periodic solutions only when $b>0$. However, since the equation I am dealing with is nonlinear, I don't know how to solve it. So far, I noticed that this can be integrated to obtain $$
y''(x)+by(x)+\tilde{c}y(x)^2=C,
$$
where $\tilde{c}=\tfrac{c}{2}$ and $C$ is an integration constant. From here I am not sure how to proceed, does anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: No way to solve $y''(x)+by(x)+\tilde{c}y(x)^2=C$ with elementary ways. Look for periodicity of solutions in other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solutions such that $y' \ne 0$ for some interval
\begin{align}
& y'' +by +cy ^2=C_1 \\
\cdot y' \implies & y'y'' +byy' +cy ^2y'=C_1y' \\
\int dx \implies & \frac{1}{2}y'^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{3}y^3 = C_1y+ C_2 \\
\text{solve for }y'^2 \implies & y'^2 = -y^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3 + C_1y+ C_2 \\
\end{align}
This can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{y'}{\sqrt{-\frac{2}{3}y^3 -y^2 + C_1y+ C_2}} = \pm 1
$$
If the conditions you have may make the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ vanish then it may be integrated further.